# Tinkerpop3 textContains predicate in DSE

Tags: datastax-enterprise-graph

This link tells that `textContains` predicate wont be supported because of vendor incompatibilities.

Am wondering if DSE graph Java API has any specific predicate that I can use to check if a vertex has a property whose `text contains X`

Something like `g.V().has("name", textContains("Humour"))`. I understand that Titan used to provide the `textContains` predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSEGraph has multiple kinds of Text predicates, which are included in the Java API.

For the available predicates and their description see http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/useSearchIndexes.html

To use the predicates in the Java Fluent API see http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.4/manual/tinkerpop/#search-and-geo

For instance you can use the predicate `Search.token()` to replace the `textContains()` predicate:

```
import com.datastax.dse.graph.api.predicates.Search;

g.V().has("name", Search.token("Humour"))
```

Comment: Please [edit] and post the specific predicates with a description of how to use them in your answer

Comment: Thanks, This is Awesome!